# No compila proyecto CUDA y CMAKE

Tags: cmake, cuda

Estoy compilando un proyecto de detección de objetos en imágenes. Esta escrito en C++, y necesita CUDA para utilizar la GPU. Mi problema, reside cuando CMAKE, busca el compilador de CUDA. Recibo este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El archivo que da error, la parte que se queja.

```
if(NOT CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_WORKS)
  PrintTestCompilerResult(CHECK_FAIL "broken")
  file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeError.log
    "Determining if the CUDA compiler works failed with "
    "the following output:\n${__CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_OUTPUT}\n\n")
  string(REPLACE "\n" "\n  " _output "${__CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_OUTPUT}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "The CUDA compiler\n  \"${CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER}\"\n"
    "is not able to compile a simple test program.\nIt fails "
    "with the following output:\n  ${_output}\n\n"
    "CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.")
else()
  if(CUDA_TEST_WAS_RUN)
    PrintTestCompilerResult(CHECK_PASS "works")
    file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeOutput.log
      "Determining if the CUDA compiler works passed with "
      "the following output:\n${__CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_OUTPUT}\n\n")
  endif()
```

Llevo 2 semanas probando todo lo que leo por foros, downgradeando versiones de Visual Studio y CUDA, pero nada funciona. 
Mi gráfica es: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti. Tengo instalado CUDA 9.2 y Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 y 2017.

Los pasos que sigo cuando quiero compilar:

1º `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64` Para establecer el compilador.

2º `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..`

3º Nunca llego a este paso, solo quedaría hacer `nmake`

He leído muchos foros, y nada me ha funcionado. Dejo el repositorio por si pudiera ser de ayuda.

https://github.com/raytrapi/Reconocimiento-Facial

Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Estás utilizando el path de Visual Studio 2019. Intenta cambiando el path a VS 2017.

Comment: Ya lo probe, con el 2019, 2017 y 2015, y aunque use la 2015 o 2017, me dice que la version es incompatible, usar solo 2013,2015 o 2017.